# Error creating package in SSIS 2008 "Library not registered"

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

Dears,
in SSIS 2008 when I try to create new package I get following error :

Error creating package
Failed to save package file "C:\Users\Mehdi\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpA99D.tmp" with error 0x8002801D "Library not registered.

**I registered both MSXML4.dll and MSXML6.dll but I still have problem.**

Comment: Can you clairfy, is it 'Library not registered' or 'Class not registered?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I had to reinstall my windows.
and it solved my issue. I know it's not a good solution :(

Answer (score 3):

I was able to fix my problem doing the following steps:

1. Repair MSXML 6.0 Parser from Add/Remove Programs
2. Re-Register the the msxml6.dll and msxml3.dll - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2416767 (See Resolution Area)

> Use the following procedure to resolve the problem:
>
> 1. Manually re-register the `MSXML6` Dlls on the system where you are experiencing the problem by executing the following commands at a
>      command prompt (you need to run these commands from an Administrative
>      Command prompt on the newer operating systems.)
>
>    On a 32-bit machine:
>
>    `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml6.dll`
>
>    `regsvr32 %windir%\system32\msxml3.dll`

I am running WindowsXP Professional, Business Intelligence Studio (Visual Studio) 2008, Microsoft SQLServer 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

You need to run regsvr on following files (regsvr32 msxml3.dll" & regsvr32 msxml6.dll)

See below link for more details:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic947330-391-1.aspx#bm947604

Comment: as I told "I registered both MSXML4.dll and MSXML6.dll but I still have problem"

Answer (score 0):

You could also try 'repairing' the MSXML6 installation from add/remove programs, or reinstalling SQL Server

As suggested in the following article:
http://www.bigresource.com/Tracker/Track-ms_sql-SORjbTEz/

I would also try restarting some of the services, and then applying any latest patches as suggested here:
http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic514859-148-1.aspx#bm514865

Comment: I installed MSXML6 parser and also I upgraded to SQL server 2008 R2!!
but it didn't work. I also restarted all of my SQL services.
I can use all of sql features except SSIS :(